# Sum up values only if there is no NA in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I want to sum up values from 3 columns only, if no column at position [i,j] has a NA value.

I tried this for the if clause, but it won't work:

```
  if(stat1[i,]!=NA&&stat2[i,]!=NA&&stat3[i,]!=NA)
```

is syntax like this possible in R?

Best regards
Jochen

Comment: Please provide example data and desired output.

Comment: the row-sum for each row

Comment: There is a `rowSums` function...

Answer (score 5):

There’s the function [`complete.cases`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/complete.cases.html) for that:

```
cols_of_interest = df[, c('stat1', 'stat2', 'stat3')]
sum(cols_of_interest[complete.cases(cols_of_interest), ])
```

The same can equivalently be written with `na.omit` as

```
sum(na.omit(cols_of_interest))
```

However, `complete.cases` is implemented as a native C function, whereas `na.omit` currently uses a quite inefficient R implementation.

Comment: `na.omit()` should also work, but I recall that being slower than `complete.cases`.

Comment: @AnandaMahto You’re right on both counts, and I’m actually puzzled now that `na.omit` isn’t simply implemented in terms of `complete.cases`, which seems like it should be trivial. Instead, `na.omit` uses a *really* naïve R implementation.